# Run async function every n seconds, wait if async function takes longer than n seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want an asynchronous function to run at a maximum rate of once a second.

```
async function update(){
    await wait_for_response();
}
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

In the above code, if the function takes longer than a second, the next update begins before the last has finished.

If update() takes longer than 1 second, I want the next update to wait until the last update is finished, running immediately afterwards.

Is there a simple built-in method or standard practice for implementing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that `setTimeout` would be a better choice in this case:

```
async function update() {
     const t1 = new Date();
     await wait_for_response();
     setTimeout(update, Math.max(0, 1000 - new Date + t1));
}
update();
```

Comment: Great answer @Luca

Comment: Very smart, but you don't need these `+` all over the place: `1000 - new Date + t1`

Answer (score 1):

This simple construct using promise chaining can handle it for you:

```
let lastPromise = Promise.resolve();
function update() {
  lastPromise = lastPromise.then(wait_for_response, wait_for_response);
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

If we're worried about the chain growing unbounded, we can use this version:

```
let lastPromise = Promise.resolve();
function update() {
  const p = lastPromise;
  function cleanup() {
    if (lastPromise === p) {
       lastPromise = Promise.resolve();
    }
  }
  lastPromise = lastPromise
    .then(wait_for_response, wait_for_response)
    .then(cleanup, cleanup);
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
```